# cpack preinstall output log

Tags: cmake, makefile, cpack

im using cpack (CMake 3.0.2) for building RPMs from my sources.
I have errors while building preinstall target, it says:

```
CPack Error:  Problem running install command: "/usr/bin/gmake"       
"preinstall"
Please check /tmp/project/.build/_CPack_Packages/Linux
/RPM/PreinstallOutput.log for errors
```

So how can i write this log into standart output while running cpack?
I tried:

```
cpack --debug --verbose
```

and

```
cpack -D CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_DEBUG=1
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way of retrieving this output - it is stored in a local buffer and being written to a log file in case of preinstall fails.
The [link](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx;h=96491aac0f5d1484062b63d93402fcbc3716f50b;hb=4811915367cc23e68e2171b83509b8a382ff1941#l652) to the corresponding source code for CMake 3.0.2:

- line #652 - the local buffer
- line #655 - build command call
- line #660 - if fail
- line #668 - redirect the buffer to the file.

This is also the case for CMake 3.2.3.